# List of general purpose transistors

Tags: transistors

It's been more than 20 years since I've done electronic design and I'm sure I've forgotten nearly everything. Now I have a purpose and want to start with a list of general purpose, readily obtainable transistors for small signal audio. By small signal I mean amplifying microphone output to feed audio cables for example. I presume that such a list might contain only five to 10 including bipolar and FET. I'm not sure I care what the packaging is.

Along those same lines, I don't know if it's possible to make a list for RF transistors, too. I have a feeling that, once I get on a roll, everything will come back to me and I'd like to keep that ball rolling.

Comment: Rather than a list of each persons favourite transistors, I think far more useful would be some guidelines on how to pick a good transistor for a particular purpose. I just looked around and I can't find any previous answers that do this well.

Answer (score 9):

I'd advise regular pin-through-hole devices in well known TO-92 (low power) and TO-220 (power) package. I think it is important to start with the knowledge where you left off. Sure, about 20 years ago we had SMD's, but a lot was still pin through hole. Above that, pin-through-hole devices are easy for breadboarding and as such to make a flying start. The devices below are cheap, easy to find and simple to use.

## Bipolar

\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{Part}&\text{Type}&I_{C,max}&h_{FE}
\\=====&================&=====&=====
\\\text{BC547B}&\text{general purpose NPN}&\text{200mA}&\text{200}
\\\text{BC557B}&\text{general purpose PNP}&\text{200mA}&\text{200}
\\\text{BC337}&\text{general purpose NPN}&\text{800mA}&\text{100}
\\\text{BC327}&\text{general purpose PNP}&\text{800mA}&\text{100}
\\\text{BC517}&\text{darlington NPN}&\text{400mA}&\text{30000}
\\\text{BC516}&\text{darlington PNP}&\text{400mA}&\text{30000}
\\\text{BD139}&\text{power NPN}&\text{1000mA}&\text{40}
\\\text{BD140}&\text{power PNP}&\text{1000mA}&\text{40}
\end{array}

## MOSFET

\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{Part}&\text{Type}&I_{D,max}&R_{DS,on}
\\=====&================&=====&=====
\\\text{BS170}&\text{general purpose N-MOSFET}&\text{500mA}&1.2\Omega
\\\text{IRF520}&\text{power N-MOSFET}&\text{9.7A}&200m\Omega
\\\text{IRF9520}&\text{power P-MOSFET}&\text{-6.8A}&480m\Omega
\end{array}

Comment: I'd love to add some logic-MOSFET's (that can easy be driven from a microcontroller), but I haven't figured out which parts the local shop at my corner sells ;o)

Comment: This list is as pointless.  Why are these particular parts more special than the many others out there?  What about price and voltage rating?  I also disagree that darlingtons should even be on a beginner list.  A beginner can always put two transistors together in the rare case they need something like a darlington.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - I did not ask for a beginner list. I asked for a short list of general purpose transistors.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the staple small signal transistors.

## NPN

2N3904 in TO-92.

MMBT3904 in SOT-23

2N2222 in TO-18, TO-92.

MMBT2222 in SOT-23

## PNP

2N3906 in TO-92.

MMBT3906 in SOT-23.

## N-channel MOSFET

2N7000 in TO-92.

2N7002 in SOT-23.

Comment: This list is pointless without explaining why these particular transistors of the many many available are ones that a beginner should have. If the answer is *this is what I use* or *this is what I've seen others use*, it's just a religious argument. This whole question needs to be closed as there is no right answer.

Comment: @OlinLathrop  The question is fine.  It asks for general purpose and obtainable.  A normal practical request.  Notice that I'm not proposing that these are teh ultimate transistors [sic].  Furthermore, anyone will read up the datasheets and come up with their *why to use* or *why not to use*, based on what they need to do.  This is left to the curious reader.  Or, it's for the curious writer (since it's a wiki).

Comment: If you're going to leave the why to the reader, then this is no answer at all.

Comment: @OlinLathrop  This is an answer to the O.P. question alright.  Sorry, Olin.