# What are some good representative transistors for a beginner's electronics class?

Tags: transistors, education

Context:  assembling coursework for a beginning electronics class.

There are various kinds of transistors commonly used in electronics circuits.  What kinds of transistors would be useful to include in a class for beginners?

The educational objective is to demonstrate:

- common uses of transistors
- what all transistors have in common
- how the various types of transistors differ

This is not a shopping question, but if you have a concrete model number that might be useful.

Comment: related (I'd say duplicate): http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/37242/7036

Comment: Do you mean both MOSFETs and Bipolar Junction Transistors, at signal (e.g. 100mA-ish) and power (at least a couple of Amps), in PNP/NPN, P-MOS/N-MOS, all in through hole for breadboard? Interested in packaged transistors (e.g. 8-way in an IC). Darlington Pair?

Comment: For small bipolars I keep as "Jellybean" transistors BC337/BC327 (through hole) or BC817/BC807 (SMD) with the -40 suffix in all cases. USAians may be heard to complain that these are "European" numbers but they are available EVERYWHERE, are cheap, high current for their package (500 mA +) OK Voltage (30V+) and high current gain (-40 = Beta = 250 - 600) and they are about as cheap as anything else in modest volume from sensible suppliers. In China completely equivalent (Motorola designed) LBC807-40 etc are very cheap . | (<= $US0.01 in 1k) | For small MOSFETS  .... later

Comment: sorry guys, there's (i think) a good question hiding in here, but I've botched it up.  I'll reask, trying to get the emphasis on the educational "compare and contrast" aspect.

Comment: BJT's, MOSFETs, and JFETs.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, please read the comment I left on the previous question... that question had definite problems, and sounds like a "shopping" question.  I'm content to let it die in its currently deleted state.  For your convenience:  sorry guys, there's (i think) a good question hiding in here, but I've botched it up. I'll reask, trying to get the emphasis on the educational "compare and contrast" aspect. –  Mark Harrison 3 hours ago

Comment: @ChetanBhargava, the previous question is not good.  It gave the mistaken impression of being a shopping question.  This question clarifies the intent of showing the various types of transistors.

Comment: @MarkHarrison if it was not good why didn't you edit it?

Comment: @ChetanBhargava in my experience on SO it's usually better that when a bad question immediately racks up the required close votes it's better to just let the question die and try to reformulate more in line with the question guidelines.

Comment: @ChetanBhargava, as you can see demonstrated so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the following are fairly-generic common transistors that have been around for a reasonably long time and likely to be around for quite a while longer.  Most are available from popular distributors and cheap from Asia.

---

BJT Complementary Pair (NPN/PNP):

- SS8050DBU / SS8550DBU : TO92, Ic = 1.5A, Vceo = 25V, "high" current for TO92.
- 2N3904 / 2N3906 : TO92, Ic = 0.2A, Vceo = 40V, cheap for low current needs.
- 2N4401 / 2N4403 : TO92, Ic = 0.6A, Vceo = 40V, some brands with Ic near SS8050DBU.
- 2N5401 / 2N5551 : TO92, Ic = 0.6A, Vceo = 150V, "higher" voltage.
- MPSA42 / MPSA92 : TO92, Ic = 0.5A, Vceo = 300V, "high" voltage.
- TIP2955/ TIP3055 : TO247, Ic = 15A, Vceo = 60V, common in older audio power amplifiers.

---

MOSFET:

- 2N7000 or 2N7002 : TO92 / SOT23, 0.2A, 60V, cheap for low current needs.
- BS170 : TO92, 0.5A, 60V, cheap-ish but supports more current than 2N7000.
- BSS138 : SOT23, 0.2A, 50V, Vgs(th) of 1.3V, common for cheap voltage-level translation, especially I2C.
- IRFB7546PbF : TO220, 75A, 60V, 6mOhm, $0.53 at Q10 from Mouser on 2014sep01, ability to switch lots of current for low price.

---

Comment: As I mentioned, it's for someone who will be receiving a "beginning electronics" kit, most likely with an Arduino.  As to the other questions (switching/audio, etc) that's one of the things I'm interested in finding an answer to, so some note as to what each of these might be used for (in a beginner's kit, remember) would be useful information.

Comment: Decent list.  (+1) I might suggest TIP31C/ TIP32C as medium power NPN/PNP in TO-220 pack.

Answer (score 1):

Logic level MOSFETs like the IRF510 will help with getting the point across with a 5v gate. They can be used with the Arduino, or any other uC with a 5v output, without needing more than a gate resistor.  Very easy to use and breadboard friendly (TO220 package), available at many retail stores, like Radio Shack here in the US, and easy enough to attach a heat sink which I consider a must for teaching.  The datasheet is well rounded with sample circuits and data-a-plenty for getting the info across to students that have different learning "styles".
[Datasheet for IRF510](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91015/sihf510.pdf)

EDIT:

I'm sure you will want to teach the difference between N and P channel transistors, so here is the P channel equivalent MOSFET for the IRF510.  It is the IRF9510. [Datasheet for the IRF9510](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91072/91072.pdf)